# jQuery - Load only those predefined css background images that are being used in document?

Tags: jquery, css, background, onload, preload

Lets say i have multiple divs with multiple background images and i want to preload them like shown below on the code. In some documents im not using all of those background images so it would make sense to preload only the ones that appear in the document instead of predefining tons of background images that always load even when theyre not used in the document.

I have this code that loads images but, Id like the images to be loaded only if they are being used.

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    var img = document.createElement('img');

    img.onload = function()
    {
        console.log("%o finished loading", this);
        //Set mouseover/mouseout event here
    };

    img.src = 'image.png', 'image2.png', 'image3.png'; // i realized that i have no idea how to add more images
});
```

Comment: From my own experience .. the background-images don't actually get downloaded until they're actually visible in the Document .. so my problem was how to pre-download them , not the other way around .. at least that stands for chrome and firefox.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend that you feed the image array to the javascript dynamically using either a database or just by passing an array that is relevant to the document you are viewing.

So you could use a function like this:

```
var BuildImages = function(imgs)
{
  for(var i = 0; i < imgs.length; i++)
  {
    var img = document.createElement('img');

    img.load(function(e)
    {
       console.log("%o finished loading", this);
       //Set mouseover/mouseout event here
    });

    img.src = imgs[i];
  }
}
```

And then call it from your document like this:

```
$(document).ready(BuildImages(new Array('image.png', 'image2.png', 'image3.png')));
```

//// UPDATE

```
var buildImages = function(divsclassname, imgs)
{
  var i = 0;
  // Loop through all divs with the class name you pass into this function
  $('.'+divsclassname).each(function(e)
  {
    // Check for has-image
    if(!$(this).hasClass('has-image'))
    {
      // If not found then set the background image and add class
      $(this).css('background-image', imags[i]).addClass('has-image');
    } 
    i++;
  });
}
```

Still call the function the same way with the addition of setting the classname of the divs

```
$(document).ready(function(e)
{
  // Define your images in an array
  var images = new Array('image.png', 'image2.png', 'image3.png');

  // pas in the images and the classname of the divs you want to have bg images
  buildImages('yourdivsclassname', images));
});
```

Comment: giving each document their own predefined code sadly doesnt quite work in this case and because they are css background images im not sure if its doable.. but how about using **if** statement to load them? as in if element has specific css value = preload?

Comment: Ah right. Yes in that case you wouldn't need to create an img element. You could just loop through the divs and if they don't have a class value of 'preload' or maybe 'hasImage' then you do div.css('background-image', imgs[i])); and div.addClass('hasImage');

Comment: that still sounds rather complicated as my javascript skills only allow me to shoot blindfolded :) ..would you be able to write me like small example of it..? editing jquery code is something i can do somewhat ^___^